# SwiftUI - Is there a known memory leak issue with Navigation View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview

It seems that when I create a view model and add a deinit method it isn't called when that view is no longer visible on the screen.

please see the attached project which demonstrates this.

Run the project, tap the log in button, you should see a console message of 'de init not logged in view view model', this behaviour is correct as that view is no longer visible so the associated view model is de-initialised.

However, now press the 'log out' button on screen, this time you won't see the de init message as it seems the logged in view view model is still there somewhere, however if you press log in again then you will see the 2x messages so only when then re-initialising the logged in view model it then de-initialises the previous one, where really it should have already been de-initialised.

If I remove the NavigationView wrapper on the logged in view then it works as expected so I think there is a bug in the Navigation View wrapper? Or am I doing something wrong?

Download the test Xcode project here as its too complex to screenshot, it is easier if you run it and take a look.[Download Test Xcode Project](https://gofile.io/?c=XjGpXh)

Comment: I recommend uploading it to [GitHub](https://github.com) instead as it's harder to trust unknown sites. Also provide some code, images or anything else that might help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I’ll do that and update my post.

Answer (score 0):

I found out If you use

`NavigationView { }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`

It will solve memory leak Apple said about `StackNavigationViewStyle`

> StackNavigationViewStyle() : A navigation view style represented by a view stack that only shows a single top view at a time.

Comment: Any explanation as to why this fixes the memory leak?